# Adding developers to Nest account

Tags: nest-api

Can I add other developers to my Nest account? I would like each member of my team to have their own Nest user account but share the same client and test devices.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not at this time.

The best practice with the current setup would be to create a group Nest Account for development (using a group email address, most IT departments have self-service for this) and a separate account for production (which you should do anyways)

If you would like to suggest better account management features, the best place to do so is on the [Product Suggestions](https://community.nest.com/community/product-suggestions) board in the [Nest Community](https://community.nest.com/).